# Getting a 2D array from 2 1D arrays (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I have two arrays x and y, which I can create a scatter plot no problem.

I am looking however to create a 1024 x 1024 array that has zeros everywhere except for where there is a point in my scatter plot.

I presume I need to use a for loop but I am a bit confused about how to go about it. As you can tell I am very much a beginner.

This is the scatter plot - I need to get an array that has 1s everywhere there is a dot and 0s everywhere else:

[image: scatter plot]

As requested, here is the code that I have currently. Originally I thought that I would have to loop through each column or row and then for each element decide whether it needed to be 0 or 1. But then I discovered I can just make each element 1 by indexing so have done that.

```
bpixdata = BPIXTAB[1].data

x = bpixdata['PIX1']
y = bpixdata['PIX2']
value = bpixdata['VALUE']

bpixarray = np.zeros([1024,1024])

bpixarray[y,x] = 1

# plt.figure('x & y scatter plot')
# plt.xlim([0,1024])
# plt.ylim([0,1024])
# plt.scatter(x,y,s=1)

# plt.figure('1024 x 1024 array')
# plt.xlim([0,1024])
# plt.ylim([0,1024])
# plt.imshow(bpixarray)
```

Comment: What kind of 2D arrays are you speaking of here? Numpy `np.ndarray()`, Python `array.array` or plain lists of lists?

Comment: EDIT: I think I might have done it on my own!

Comment: oh sorry, didn't realise I couldn't put an enter in.

x and y are my two np.arrays that I started with.

I have used bpixarray = np.zeros([1024,1024]) and then bpixarray[y-1,x-1] = 1

Comment: Hi Serge, I am using numpy arrays. Thanks. Do you see any issues with my solution?

Comment: It looks fine for me, if it gives the expected result.

Comment: Please edit and add some code representing the original data.

Comment: Hi decadenza, I have now added the code as requested.